# What is unclear in my question?

Tags: discussion, on-hold-questions

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313169/how-to-prove-that-if-a-is-infinite-then-omega-le-a-using-the-axiom-of) yesterday, and it was put on hold because "it is not clear what I am asking". Is it really unclear? How clearer can I be in asking my question?

Comment: I don't think that the comments are fair on this question. The use of $\omega$ in set theory is as standard as the use of $\Bbb C$ in functional analysis. Using that as an excuse to close the question is preposterous. That being said, I do think that the question could benefit from a bit more details from the OP, especially these thoughts and ideas which are supposedly not worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, a pro-tip for free: $$\Huge\textrm{The title }\textbf{IS NOT }\textrm{part of the body!!!}$$In other words, your body should be self-contained.

Comment: And if you write that there is some other question where you don't fully understand the answers, it might be a *very* good idea to point out what is unclear about these answers.

Comment: @Asaf Your comment would be much more helpful if you explained why the title should not be considered to be part of the body, esp. considering that the OP is new.

Comment: Omega, I saw that you deleted your question. It should be noted that re-posting a question that was closed is generally not well-received here. So if you want to post this question again, I suggest that you take to heart all the comments and suggestions that you received about elaborating more. I would be very happy to answer your question, if I knew exactly what is unclear to you.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the entire body of your Question:

> I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250119/proving-dedekind-finite-implies-finite-assuming-countable-choice) for example, but I don't understand the proof there. Can you please explain how to do that?
>
> I tried to prove it and I have some thoughts, though I don't think they are worth mentioning.

Yes, a reasonable Reader might find it *unclear what you are asking*.  From the brief contents of the Question's body, it seems you have difficulty with something that was proved in various places, and in particular in the one linked previous Question.

But what difficulty are you having?  Are there definitions that are unfamiliar to you?  Is there a step that seems to be a leap/unsupported?  Is the approach taken a dubious one, either intuitively or because it seems similar to faulty proofs you've seen?

While your thoughts and attempts may seem "not worth mentioning" to you, you have the advantage of your Readers.  You are already familiar with those thoughts and attempts, and Readers will have to guess at what about previous proofs seem inadequate or misguided or incomprehensible in your view.

Fill in those blanks (self-contained problem statement in the body, summary of your attempts or other context to let Readers see where you may need help), and the Question will be more valuable as content for Math.SE.